# Divergence Theorem/Integration by Parts on Unbounded Domains

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Are there any formulations of the Divergence Theorem or integration by parts formulae that apply to unbounded domains?

Comment: You should give more information about the particular situation you need such a formulation.  If you are integrating something which decays rapidly "at infinity" then you may be in luck.

Comment: Lots of computation of integrals is based on that: residue theorems plus vanishing at infinity. Roughly, you should write a theorem for a bounded domain and see what happens in the limit: as @StevenGubkin points out, with luck, the integral over the boundary will tend to $0$. (So, "rapidly" means, roughly, faster than $r^{{\dim}-1}$.)

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Omega$ be a $C^1$ open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $X$ be a continuous vector field on $\Omega$ such that $\text{div}X\in L^1(\Omega)$ ($\text{div}X$ is the distribution divergence). We  equip $\partial \Omega$ with the measure $d\sigma$, induced by the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb R^n$; moreover we  ask that, with $\nu$ standing for the outer unit normal to $\Omega$
$$
\langle X,\nu\rangle\in L^1(\partial \Omega).
$$
Then the Gauss-Green formula holds:
$$
\int_{\Omega}\text{div}X\  dx=\int_{\partial \Omega}\langle X,\nu\rangle d\sigma.
$$

Comment: I don't think this works if $\Omega$ is unbounded. E.g., $\Omega=\Bbb R$ (with $\partial\Omega=\varnothing$) and $X$ pretty much any function (with the derivative summable on $\Bbb R$ if you want the integral to converge).

Comment: For unbounded domains, I think you'll also want to assume something like $X = o(|x|^{1-n})$ as $|x| \to \infty$.  Then you can use the result for the intersection of $\Omega$ with a ball of radius $r$, and have the part of the right side for the surface of the ball go to $0$ as $r \to \infty$.

Comment: I agree with both comments. If $f$ is a continuous function on the real line with a distribution derivative in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, the Lebesgue differentiation theorem tells you that $f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^xf'(t) dt$. For a given $x_0$, the rhs has a limit when $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$, so does the lhs. The 1D formula holds iff $f(+\infty)=f(-\infty)$. In more dimensions, Robert Israel's suggestion works.